# Jmeter response assertion is failing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, assertion, jmeter-5.0

I have one API request in which on success i get below tag in its response:

```
<TktNum xmlns=\"\">12012</TktNum>
```

And i have response assertion set as Text Response and pattern rule as Contains with text as mentioned below:

```
<TktNum xmlns=\"\">
```

[image]

But, Jmeter is failing this assertion even for success.

how can i get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps) article

> The most commonly used assertion is the Response Assertion, which checks whether a response text/body/code/message/header contains, matches, or equals a specified pattern.
>
> The Pattern can be either be:
>
> - a “string” for “Equals” or “Substring” clauses
> - a “Perl5-style” Regular Expression for “Contains” or “Matches” clauses

So I believe you need to amend your expression to something like:

```
<TktNum xmlns=\\"\\">(\d+)</TktNum>
```

More information:

- [PCRE - Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](https://www.pcre.org/)
- [Apache JMeter - Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Select the option `Substring` in the Pattern Matching Rules Section.

[image]

> Equals, Substring: plain text, case-sensitive

If you want to continue with the `Contains` option your need to pre-pend the escape character ```with another `\`

```
<TktNum xmlns=\\"\\">
```